# Can i fetch a php array file on a server using JSON in javascript to display the data?

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

I am trying to get a .php file on a server in my neatbeans software using
JavaScript with JSON. I am a begginer and I am not finding any solution.

I get this error in developers tool:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://evercodeplus.com/get_products.php' from origin 'http://localhost:8084' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Also I don't know why the pro.insertAdjacentHTML is not working.

I have seen people mentioning `json_encode`, but I don't know how to use it.

```js
        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://evercodeplus.com/get_products.php'  , true);
        xmlhttp.onload = function (){
        var ourData = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        showHTML(ourData);
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
};

function showHTML(data)
{
    var htmlString = "";
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        htmlString += "<ul>" + data[i].name + ".</ul>";
    }

    document.getElementById("product").innerHTML=htmlString;
    pro.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','htmlString');
}
```

Comment: can you use ```jquery``` it will be more calling ```ajax``` simple than doing this.

Comment: Or he could just use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which would be easier still, but it still won't work because the request is being made to a different server than the code came from, and that server has no instructions to honour such a request, hence the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) message.

Comment: I always use a  jquery.I use this line of code.                                             
         <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: You might be loading jQuery but you're not using it anywhere in the code snippet you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer `json_encode`, then the function shoud wrap the return array result of `get_product.php`. The return result will be in json format so that you can process them.

For CORS, make sure the server allow `cross origin resource sharing` and check if your request method support CORS.